# select data from nested arrays inside jsonb

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have jsonb like this:

```
{
    "level1":{
        "level2":[
            {
                "level3":[
                    {"priority":17},
                    {"priority":5},
                    {"priority":22}
                ]
            },
            {
                "level3":[
                    {"priority":15},
                    {"priority":25}
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I need to select all priority with full path.

I have tried to use jsonb_array_elements(...) with ordinality, but i can get only first index.

```
with src_1 as (
    select
        array['level1', 'level2', ordinality-1]::varchar[] as path,
        value as node
    from jsonb_array_elements(JJJ)#>'{level1,level2}' with ordinality as j
)

select
    path || array['level3']::varchar[] as path,
    node #> '{level3}'
from src_1
```

I need result, like this:

```
path                                 priority
==================================== ========
{'level1','level2','0','level3','0'}       17
{'level1','level2','0','level3','1'}        5
{'level1','level2','0','level3','2'}       22
{'level1','level2','1','level3','0'}       15
{'level1','level2','1','level3','1'}       25
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    array['level1', 'level2', a.ordinality-1,'level3',b.ordinality-1]::varchar[] as path,
    b.value->>'priority'
from
    jsonb_array_elements(JJJ #> '{level1,level2}') with ordinality as a,
    jsonb_array_elements(value->'level3') with ordinality as b
```